# SKLearn Poisson regression predictor formula print/export

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, poisson

I'm using `sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor` and I would like to export the equation of my resulting predictor.

I understand how to print the linear equation using:
`poisson_reg.coef_` and `poisson_reg.intercept_`, however I'm really confused of how the actual predictor equation looks like in practice.

My use case is just to take/copy the math formula with the resulting coefficients & intercept and use it on a different platform.